# Google Design Cards - Rich Media Giffs Acceptable?

Tags: material-design, google

Going by the specs for [Google Design Cards](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/cards.html#cards-content-blocks), does anyone know if animated gifs are acceptable for the rich media?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this article reads it seems it's not possible due to Android capabilities, hope it helps.

> "The layouts built by the Card class use Android's ImageView to represent their images, and the ImageView widget does not support animated GIFs. You would need to construct your own layout and manage the animation manually."

[Could one use an animated gif as part of card.addImage(uri) in an immersion card on Glass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925965/could-one-use-an-animated-gif-as-part-of-card-addimageuri-in-an-immersion-card)

Comment: If you could - please copy the relevant portion into your answer.